# How to build escrow feature in my website like paxful.com

Tags: bitcoin-core

i am building an exchange bitcoin website,but i want to know how to make the website a 3rd party between buyer and a seller to be an escrow like paxful.com

any ideas about an API or a service that could be included in a website ?